# Is there another method to load a video file into a video element?

Tags: nuxt.js

My file upload-er has mysteriously broken and when converting the file to an ObjectURL the video becomes null for some reason. This did not happen before but after revisiting my project and updating all my packages this functionality has broken.

The solution is pretty straight forward but I have no clue how to fix this.

```
getAvatar(e){
    let file = e.target.files[0]
    let reader = new FileReader()
    let limit = 1024 * 1024 * 2

    if(file.size > limit) {
        this.toast('error','File is too large')
        return false
    }

    reader.onloadend = (file) => {
        this.form.avatar = reader.result
        this.avatar = this.form.avatar
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)

    this.form.a_ext = (/[.]/.exec(file.name)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(file.name)[0] : undefined;
    this.form.a_type = file.type
    this.type = this.form.a_type.split('/').shift()

    if (file){
        let preview = URL.createObjectURL(file)
        switch(this.type){
            case "image":
                console.log(preview)
                this.getImageDimensions(preview)
                .then((dimensions) => {
                    this.form.a_dimensions = dimensions
                    this.handleResize(dimensions)
                })
                break;
            case "video":
                var video = document.getElementById('avatarVideo')
                var oldSrc = document.getElementById('videoSrc')
                if (oldSrc) { video.removeChild(oldSrc) }
                var src = document.createElement('source')
                src.setAttribute('id','videoSrc')
                src.setAttribute('src',preview)
                console.log(preview)
                video.appendChild(src)
                video.load()
                video.play()

                this.getVideoDimensions()
                .then((dimensions) => {
                    this.form.a_dimensions = dimensions
                    this.handleResize(dimensions)
                })
                .catch((e) =>{
                    this.toast('error',e.message)
                })
                break;
            default:
                this.toast('error','File type not supported')
                break;
        }
    } else {
        this.toast('error','File is null')
    }
}
```

It creates the blob URL but ends up being null

```
blob:http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/ab1b04c8-288e-4b5b-b12b-366639ec9794
```

Images work fine with this code and even if I refactor it to its simplest form I still can not get the video files to work again.

The error occurs during

```
video.appendChild(src)
```

Error

```
error TypeError: "video is null"
    NuxtJS 9
        getAvatar
        invokeWithErrorHandling
        invoker
        invokeWithErrorHandling
        $emit
        onFileChange
        invokeWithErrorHandling
        invoker
        _wrapper
vendors.app.js:28236:7246
    NuxtJS 15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out the solution through trial and error. I basically had to rearrange the code after the file reader "reader" to be housed within the onloadend event. This finally allowed me to preview videos again without uploading them.

However, strangely my code for removing video src nodes broke also so i had to opt for removing the innerHTML of the video element in order to remove old src nodes and load a newly selected video.

It would be interesting if anyone could tell me why my code broke. My previous setup was working fine before i upgraded nuxt and all the packages i was using but i still don't understand how that could have broke this code.

```
getAvatar(e){
    let file = e.target.files[0]
    let reader = new FileReader()
    let limit = 1024 * 1024 * 2

    if(file.size > limit) {
        this.toast('error','File is too large')
        return false
    }

    this.form.a_ext = (/[.]/.exec(file.name)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(file.name)[0] : undefined;
    this.form.a_type = file.type
    this.type = this.form.a_type.split('/').shift()

    if (file){
        let preview = URL.createObjectURL(file)
        reader.onloadend = (file) => {
            this.avatar = reader.result
            this.form.avatar = reader.result
            switch(this.type){
                case "image":
                    this.getImageDimensions(preview)
                    .then((dimensions) => {
                        this.form.a_dimensions = dimensions
                        this.handleResize(dimensions)
                    })
                    break;
                case "video":
                    var video = document.getElementById('avatarVideo')
                    video.innerHTML = '';
                    var src = document.createElement('source')
                    src.setAttribute('id','videoSrc')
                    src.setAttribute('src',preview)
                    video.appendChild(src)
                    video.load()
                    video.play()

                    this.getVideoDimensions()
                    .then((dimensions) => {
                        this.form.a_dimensions = dimensions
                        this.handleResize(dimensions)
                    })
                    .catch((e) =>{
                        this.toast('error',e.message)
                    })
                    break;
                default:
                    this.toast('error','File type not supported')
                    break;
            }
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    } else {
        this.toast('error','File is null')
    }
}
```